# python mod_wsgi file permission for write

Tags: python, permissions, mod-wsgi

I have redhat server and apache and mod_wsgi installed and configured. All is working fine. I can send HTTP request and my Flask-restfull API response it properly. But I want to write to file I got following error in Apache error log.

> *PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied*

I am using following way to write to file:

```
with open('myfile','a') as f:
   f.write('test')
```

it work if I run from command line but from apache it is not working.

I have created group `'web'` and it `'myuser'` and `'apache'` user assigned to this user.
And file to which I want to write has `myuser:web` ownership and `777` chmod.

**What is problem in this case?**

Comment: It might be better to give a full path for the file location. Do you even have an idea where the program tries to save the file? It might be the folder where the script is, but most likely it's not.

Comment: I am using full path. my script and file I want to write it is in same folder. Problem is with ownership of file. Because I run call this script with HTTP request.

Comment: Your example code in question is not showing a full path even if you say it is. Always better to show the actual code you are using. Also go read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user These issues are covered in the documentation for mod_wsgi.

Comment: Dear Graham, I am using full path , there is no doubt. Problem is related to permission for 'apache' user which run myscript. 

I create user called 'scriptor' and group called 'web' and then I add scriptor and apache users to web group. Then I create file with scriptor and its chown is sccriptor:web. Considering that this users are on the same group apache user should write to this file but Permission Error rised.